# MDX calculated measure 2022 Vs 2023 units

Tags: indexing, mdx, measure

i have a pivot table with 2022 and 2023 shipped units cols.

Looking to use an MDX calculated measure to calculate the index of these (2023/ 2022)*100

I have a calander table with year and 2022 and 2023 are in year.

shipped units is whit in Measures.

Thanks.

[Measures].[Shipped Units],[Calendar].[Year].&[2023]/[Measures].[Shipped Units],[Calendar].[Year].&[2022]*100

error message

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to at a minimum use braces to make sure that the numerator and denominator are `tuples`:

```
([Measures].[Shipped Units],[Calendar].[Year].&[2023])/([Measures].[Shipped Units],[Calendar].[Year].&[2022])*100
```

Further I'd rather use `MDX`s function `DIVIDE`:

```
DIVIDE(
   ([Measures].[Shipped Units],[Calendar].[Year].&[2023])
  ,([Measures].[Shipped Units],[Calendar].[Year].&[2022])
)*100
```